# Merging Attachments in Salesforce into a single attachment - is this possible natively?

Tags: apex

I'm looking into merging multiple attachments (.pdfs) into a single attachment.

The research I have done so far suggests that there is no native way to achieve this in Apex.

- https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/06/cloud-based-pdf-merge-solution-for-forcecom.html
- [Combine multiple PDF's together and attach them in a mail?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50438/combine-multiple-pdfs-together-and-attach-them-in-a-mail)
- [Print multiple CRM content PDF files at once](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10567/print-multiple-crm-content-pdf-files-at-once)

The only feasible way seems is to either leverage an App, such as CongaComposer or DocuSign (paid for) or, as per [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/06/cloud-based-pdf-merge-solution-for-forcecom.html), to make a webservice to the Google App Engine.

Has anyone been successful in merging attachments together in Salesforce without the assistance of a paid-for App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to be able to manipulate the file with the equivalent of Adobe Acrobat Exchange or similar in order to merge 2 or more PDF documents into a single document. Apex simply doesn't have those capabilities. You're correct that you'd need to leverage either a 3rd party application or a some kind of provider accessed via web services.